# Why are some SonarQube rules not present in SonarLint in Visual Studio

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I didn´t understand this bellow difference between SonarLint and SonarQube.

Is my sonarLint configuration missing?

See print bellow

[Compare rules from SonarQube to SonarLint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EYOD.png)

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# code, both SonarLint for VS ("SLVS") and the Scanner for MSBuild ("S4MSB") use the SonarC# Roslyn analyser.

SLVS uses the version of SonarC# embedded in the VSIX; S4MSB uses the version embedded in the SonarQube SonarC# plugin. You might see slightly different sets of issues being reported if different versions of the SonarC# analyser are being used as the analyser is under active development (e.g. new rules being added, false-positives and bugs being fixed).

A more common source of differences is the configuration of the set of rules to be run.
The same default set of rules is used by both SLVS and SonarQube, but this is configurable. In SonarQube, rules configuration is done using Quality Profiles. In VS, it is done using the standard VS ruleset mechanism.

The rule S1244 in your screenshot is disabled by default, so my guess is that your SonarQube project is using a customised Quality Profile that has enabled the rule.

If you are using SLVS in "standalone mode" (i.e. independently of SonarQube/SonarCloud), you'd configure the rules you want to run using rulesets.

If you have a project on SonarQube/SonarCloud and want to use the same set of rules locally in SLVS, you can use "connected mode" to link your VS solution to your SonarQube/SonarCloud project from the Team Explorer in VS. SLVS will generate a ruleset from the Quality Profile and configure the projects in your solution to use the generated ruleset.